# Is there a way to use external variable as choice parameters in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, deployment

I want to fetch data from my sql Table and use them as a choice parameters in Jenkins

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
| 11 |
| 23 |
| 45 |
| 72 |
|  5 |
| 16 |
| 71 |
| 18 |
+----+
```

I want to use these IDs as a choice parameter in Jenkins in order to build using one of these ID i.e. build with parameters using these ID numbers as Parameter

I simply want a drop down with these ID numbers as the choices before I build and the selected choice can be used as parameter to the script in the build step.

What would be the way of achieving this?
Please help